# What's the term to describe this combination?

Tags: algorithm, theory, probability

There are 4 items: 1, 2, 3, and 4. If we just allow the following combinations, what should we call them? I forgot it. Is it called nCr?

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
2 3 4
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: If this is the powerset, you're missing the empty set as noted as well  as the set `1 3 4`.  For a set with `n` elements, its powerset will have `2^n` elements (it's essentially all binary strings of some length where `1` means the element at that position was included and `0` means the element was not included).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). Note that the power set also contains the empty set.

Comment: Ahh... my discrete maths came back to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **powerset** of your original set, with one exception.

The powerset of a set is the set of all possible subsets. Your list is that, except that your list does not include the empty set, which is a subset of all sets.